# mapping in $H_{c}^k(X,\mathbb{Z})$

Tags: homology-cohomology

If Y is closed subset of X, do anyone know what is the mapping from $H_{c}^k(X,\mathbb{Z})$ to   $H_{c}^k(Y,\mathbb{Z})$ ? Is it differ if X is an open subset of Y.

$H_{c}^k$ is a cohomology with compact support.

Comment: related: [Long exact sequence for cohomology with compact supports](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/521429/)

Comment: But I don't understand the difference with open and closed case..

Comment: You mean that $Y$ is an open subset of $X$, right? I don't see a reason a mapping should exist otherwise.

Comment: Yes, it is. Open and close subset

Comment: What cohomology theory are you considering? Sheaf cohomology?

Comment: Singular homology

Answer (score 1):

The inclusion $Y\to X$ induces a morphism of chain complexes $h: C_*(Y)\to C_*(X)$ and, hence, a morphism of cochain complexes $h^*: C^*(X)\to  C^*(Y)$. Now, the inclusion $Y\to X$ is a proper map (here we use that $Y$ is closed: a closed subset of a compact is compact!). Thus, $h^*$ sends compactly supported cochains to compactly supported cochains; hence, by restriction, we obtain a morphism
$$
h': C_c^*(X)\to C^*_c(Y). 
$$
As any morphism of chain complexes, $h'$ will induce homomorphisms of homology groups
$$
H^*_c(X):=H_*(C_c^*(X))\to H_*(C^*_c(Y))=:H^*_c(Y). 
$$
That's all.