# Is the first term of this sequence trivial?

Tags: abstract-algebra, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, exact-sequence, cw-complexes

I have a CW-complex $X$ with a closed subset $C$ and its complement $U$. Like in this similar [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/521429/long-exact-sequence-for-cohomology-with-compact-supports), I am working with the following long exact sequence of cohomology with compact supports:

$$ \cdots \to H^{i-1}_c (X) \to H^{i-1}_c (C) \to H^i_c(U) \to H^i_c (X) \to H^i_c (C) \to H^{i+1}_c (U) \to \cdots$$

I additionally know that two of the terms are trivial and can therefore form the following exact sequence:

$$ 0 \to H^{1}_c (C) \xrightarrow{i} H^2_c(U) \to H^2_c (X) \xrightarrow{r} H^2_c (C) \xrightarrow{t}\ 0$$

Does it follow that $H^{1}_c (C)=0$?

Here is the reason I think so. We have a short exact sequence:
$$ 0 \to \ker{r} \to H^2_c (X) \xrightarrow{r} H^2_c (C) \xrightarrow{t} 0.$$

Then
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\ker{r} & = H^2_c (X) - r^{-1}(\text{im} r - \{0\}) \\
 & = H^2_c (X) - r^{-1}(\text{ker} t - \{0\}) \\
 & = H^2_c (X) - r^{-1}(H^2_c (C)- \{0\}) \\
 & \cong H^2_c (X) - (H^2_c (C)- \{0\}) \\
 & \cong H^2_c (U).
\end{split}
\end{equation}

I assume I am in error because the result is too strong, and I also assume the error is the last isomorphism. All wisdom is appreciated!

Comment: The final isomorphism is very suspicious. $H^2_c(C)$ is not naturally a subgroup of $H^2_c(X)$. Even if it where, $H^2_c(X)\setminus H^2_c(C)=H^2_c(X\setminus C)$ looks dodgy. I'm not confident enough on cohomology with compact supports to say anything more though