# Examples using this long exact sequence of cohomology

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, geometric-topology, cw-complexes, mayer-vietoris-sequence

I began reading [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/2204.08968) paper (also provided below), and I would really appreciate if someone could help me with the premises behind the first sentence. I have not been able to find the given long exact sequence in my books, and I don't want to wrongly start generalizing it.

This is the sequence when $U$ is an open subspace of X:

$$\cdots \to H^n_c(U) \to H^n_c(X) \to H^n_c(X-U) \to H^{n+1}_c(U) \to \cdots$$

**First Attempt of an Example**

The first example I tried was $X=\mathbb{R}^2$ with $(X-U)$ a closed disk in the plane. I then made the compact exhaustion of $U$ to be 2-dimensional rings around $U$ that grow in size to cover $U$. The 2-rings get larger and larger and also closer and closer to the closed disk. Then each 2-ring quotiented by the rest of $U$ is a torus. That is a 2-ring quotiented by the inner and outer ring, which is a 1-sphere. So $H_c^n(U)$ is equivalent to the cohomology of a 2-sphere, which I think is R, 0, R for n=0, 1, 2 resp.

**Second Attempt of an Example**

Next I wanted to try an example where neither $U$ nor $X-U$ are compact. So I let $X$ be an infinite space that is made up of infinitely many copies of $\mathbb{R}^2$ branching off each other. I took $U$ to be the infinite open subset that is made up of infinitely many copies of $\mathbb{R}^2 - S$ where $S$ is a 2-simplex that is a square. Then $X-U$ is a connected space that is made up of infinitely many copies of a square. There are infinitely many intersecting planes in this example, but $U$ is open, although infinite.

Long story short, the exact sequence given in the paper says that $H^n_c(X) = H^n_c(X-U)$ if $H^n_c(U)$ is trivial for all $n$, but I don't want to work out more examples before I know all the conditions on $X$ and $U$. Which leads to:

**Question:**

Where is the error in my reasoning in the above two examples?

Does this long exact sequence hold when $U$ and its complement are unbounded?

Is the definition of an "open subspace" of a CW complex really more strict than I am making it? I am using the definiton given [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/closed+subspace).

(I will keep looking for the answers to these questions myself and update when I find something, but help from a mathematician would be awesome.)

Update: The answer written by @Hanspeter Kraft [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/521429/long-exact-sequence-for-cohomology-with-compact-supports) reiterates that the long exact sequence holds for CW complexes $X$, but there is no discussion about the open and closed subspaces.

[image]

Comment: How did you arrive at $H^*_c(U) = 0$ in the first example (the one where $U$ is the complement of a closed disk in the plane)?

Comment: @BrianShin Thank you. I wrote it out again, and now I think it is the same as the cohomology of a 1-sphere. I elaborated in the question. If you could check it, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Thank you. I added the link.